# What is happened behind the scene, when you submit a file using POST

Tags: file, http, post, submit

When a user selected a file and click submit, all the other input fields are transferred in HTTP header. But what happened to the file? How did it get transferred to the server? What protocol has been used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you POST data to a server, said data will be transmitted in the HTTP body rather than the HTTP header. The file will be encoded as either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` (as described in [the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)).